# Click function does not return ,causing the test to hang

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I m automating our web application, and I have a function for the logout.

**The scenario is** : When I click on the logout button, a pop up is displayed and  the ok button in the pop up needs to be clicked in order for the logout functionality to be completed.

**Problem** : Below given script,

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(GUIProperties.LOUGOUT));
                    wait(5);
                    log.info("clicking element ");
                    element.click();
                    log.info("Clicked element ");
innerButton= GUIProperties.LOGOUT_OK;
                if(isElementPresent(innerButton)) {
                    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(innerButton));
                    ele.click();
                }
```

The 1st log.info "Clicking element" is displayed in the console , and the click function happens , but it does not move from there onward. ie It does not print the next log statement.And the click on the popup also does not trigger. This problem is only observed in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Whats the version of IE?

Comment: @Grasshopper its IE 11

Comment: Something similar to your issue - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/webdriver-clicking-button-issue-in-ie-11... Have you tried sendKeys(Kes.ENTER) instead for IE.

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried that and also the answer given in the link you have shared, the capabilities, nothing works, sporadically the capalibilites configuration  works, but most of the time it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for the above issue is ,

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```